# Ubuntu on Pi Zero 2W Wifi not listed

Tags: wifi, ubuntu, pi-zero-w-2

I can't figure how to setup a Wifi connection on my pi zero 2, running on Ubuntu server 21.
I tried many different things and here the results:

- Raspbian lite: everything works fine
- Ubuntu server: can connect on my Android Phone's Wifi but not on my home router. Both using `network-config` file
- Manjaro: I see a bunch of neighbours' Wifis but not my router

I disabled 5Ghz network to avoid any problem, I also specified bsid, but nothing worked.

Any idea on how I should fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution.
Turns out my router was using channel 13 which is somehow not supported by ubuntu because it not a US channel.